# How can I align the text in a TextSwitcher?

Tags: android

I want to justify my TextSwitcher in android. But I am not getting any solution for that. I have added a TextSwitcher like below-

```
 <TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/ts_place"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/left_offset"/>
```

But the text showing with no alignment both left and right like below-

> The Starks ruled the North until the betrayal of Robb Stark at the Red
>   Wedding by Roose Bolton. Since then, it has been the Boltons who rule
>   the North with their seat shifted to Winterfell from the Dreadfort.
>   Karstark, Manderly, Umber, Reed and Mormont are the major vassal
>   houses who swear allegiance to the Warden of the North.

I want make these text left and right aligned properly.

Comment: Please tell us which layout you're using (Linear, Grid, Relative,...) Maybe show us some more code of this layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewFactory and override the makeView function to use your own custom view/textview for your text switcher.  You should be able to set properties on that view.

```
TextSwitcher exampleTextSwitcher;
exampleTextSwitcher.setFactory(textSwitcherFactory);


private ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory textSwitcherFactory = new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory()
{
    @Override
    public View makeView()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_timer_textview, null);
    }
};
```

view_timer_textview.xml

```
<TextView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it directly through code for example:

```
TextSwitcher textSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.your_id_text_switcher);

        textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            tvSwitcher = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tvSwitcher.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            tvSwitcher.setTextSize(18);
            //edit lines as follows
            tvSwitcher.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
            return tvSwitcher;
        }
    });
```